# Удаленная отладка в проекте C++ на Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2017, cmake, remote-debugging

Есть проблема удаленной отладки проекта на плюсах. Расклад таков:

1. Хост машина на Windows 10 x64
2. Таргет сервер на Windows 10 x64 с установленной тулзой MSVC Remote Debugging и настроенным разрешением в брандмауэре разрешение на TCP 4022 для msvsmon x64
3. Mikrotik маршрутизатор между хост и таргет машинами (Проброшен в обе стороны 4022 порт по TCP)
4. CMake Проект на C++, которы генерирует уже решение для MSVC 2017. В проекте настраивается remote debugging на таргете и автодеплой **только для одного из проектов**

Проблема: при настройке удаленной отладки вылезает ошибка, что mcvcmon не запушен на таргет машине. Но, успешно деплоит сам exe, также выводит, что не может задеплоить ZERO_CHECK проект столько раз, равное количеству проектов в решении минус успешно задеплоеный exe. На таргет машине видно, что был коннект и все, пусто. В хелпе ошибки вывод на страницу проблем msdn, где я нашел как делать разрешение для программ на коннект по портам в брандмауере, использование одной и той же учетки. Пробовал и без авторизации.

Но, если создать простой проект, то он успешно отлаживается...

Еще не пробывал варинат с простом cmake проекте, но есть подозрение, что cmake что-то добавляет лишнее и это вот и ломает отладку.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался?

**PS:** 
Ошибка деплоя такая:

`1>Error: Unable to deploy local file 'path_to_zero_check\ZERO_CHECK' (remote file path 'C:\Debug\ZERO_CHECK')`

**PS2:**
Есть еще такой нюасн. Такая же ошибка будет и для простого проекта, если не сделать одинаковые настройки удаленной отладки для всех конфигураций проекта.

**PS3** Минимальный проект:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for CMakeProject1, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeProject1 "CMakeProject1.cpp" "CMakeProject1.h")

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```

CMakeProject1.cpp и CMakeProject1.h автогенерируемые студией пример "Hello world".

Далее, в директории генерируем решение студии `cmake .`

Настраиваем удаленную отладку и деплой для проекта CMakeProject1:
[image: Remote debugging settings]
[image: Деплой]

Запускаем от админа Remote Debug на сервере и пуска с админом:
[image: Первый запуск Remote Debugger на сервере]

Далее я деплою проект:

```
1>------ Deploy started: Project: CMakeProject1, Configuration: Debug Win32 
------
1>Error: Unable to deploy local file '\CMakeProject1\Debug\ZERO_CHECK' (remote file path 'C:\Tem\remote-debug\ZERO_CHECK')
1>Error: Unable to deploy local file '\CMakeProject1\Debug\ZERO_CHECK' (remote file path 'C:\Tem\remote-debug\ZERO_CHECK')
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

exe задеплоился:
[image: Exe в деплой директории]

Коннект был:
[image: Коннект был]

Запускаем:
[image: Коннект еще раз был]
[image: Запуск удаленной отладки]

Comment: Не понял ни одного слова, но плюсанул за организацию удаленной отладки.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, пока что попытки)

Comment: Если руками создать в студии проект, сконфигурировать ремот дебаг, то именно из студии будет работать удаленный дебаг? (для понимания где именно в вашей цепочке проблема)

Comment: Убедитесь точно что деплой выполняется, укажите явно папку для деплоя. Проверьте что настраиваете и стартуете одну и туже конфигурацию, галки деплой не забудьте при этом.

Comment: Вообще удаленный отладчик ведет лог у себя в окне. Студия при старте тоже лог ведет что там выводится?

Comment: Права какие у пользователя под которым отлаживаетесь на удаленной машине? Проекты которые не нужны выгрузите из решения.

Comment: Лучше бы вы привели минимальный проект, на котором проявляется такое поведение и шаги для его повторения. Вот например вы выставили этот "один из проектов" в качестве стартового? Как этот проект зависит от остальных? Как вы его собираете и запускаете отладку?

Comment: @VTT, с минимальным будет проблемы, и что вы понимаете под примером минимального проекта студии, который я могу сюда скинуть?

Comment: @Cerbo, пользователь входит в домена/группа, на сервера она вся является админской для машины. И я написал, что коннект происходит на стороне и какая ошибка вылезает у студии. В вопросе все есть.

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @goldstar_labs, Да, через wizard дефолтный проект. И там уже настраивается удаленная отладка. В PS2 я еще написал нюанс.

Comment: @VTT, не в коде дело. Могу кинуть `std::cout << "Hello wordl" << std::endl;`, если хочешь. А настройки студии слишком долго придеться описывать. Как руки дойдут, попробую найти такой пример и скинуть хотя бы скриншоты.

Comment: Нужен воспроизводимый пример, чтобы что-то кроме вас тут смог получить такую же ошибку, как и у вас. `std::cout << "Hello wordl" << std::endl;` не является таким примером.

Comment: Думаю у вас проблема в конфиге CMake, судя по всему при отладке он что-то делает не так, но тут слишком много вариантов, чтобы что-то советовать

Comment: @goldstar_labs, я и предполагаю, что cmake делает что-то "ужасное", что мешает настроить отладку. Осталось проверить теорию, что будет, если в решении будет 2 простых проекта и только один будет настроен на отладку. Может быть студия на это ругается, лог деплоя выше на это намекает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема полностью определена: проект **ZERO_CHECK** мешает удаленной отладке.
Если отключить его построение, то уходит проблема неудачного deploy, но остается проблема с Windows Firewall. Скорее всего это баг MSVC (Надо бы им написать). Убирается установкой `set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION ON)` в корневом CMakeLists.txt для отмены регенерации проектов (Какой-то способ просто его отключить на время, кроме  его полного удаления не нашел). Отладка удалась)

Answer (score 0):

Немного из моего опыта
1) Ремот тулз должны быть того же выпуска (2015/2017) что и студия
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017
2) Сеть на обеих машинах должна быть "Частная"
3) "Дополнительные параметры общего доступа" должно быть включено сетевое обнаружение и общий доступ к файлам и принтерам
4) Авторизацию на ремот дебагере лучше отключить если не используется полнофункциональная доменная сеть
5) Как ни странно иногда у меня ничего не работает и помогает на обеих компах открыть в проводнике сеть и подождать пока винда просканирует сеть, после чего два компа начинают видеть друг друга
6) Брэндмауэр лучше отключить или вручную добавить туда студию + тул

Comment: Ну, я все из этого делал, кроме 5 и 6 пунктов. 5 бесполезен, открыты только некоторые порты. 
6 пункт только в исключения брандмауэра добавлял, но не отключал. Отсалось еще попробовать все снести (Remote debug), но это ждать выходные, когда сервер не нужен.